# html() method in jquery need to return textarea with value

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to store the html element of a table which includes textarea tags also.
I need to store the textarea with value when I call html() method in jquery.

Code in html:

```
<div id="test">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

After user input for textarea field, for example user inputs "Mango".
Then when I call
var test = $('#test').html();

it should return the output as "< textarea >Mango< / textarea >"

Any ideas please. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To get the value of the textarea, use: `$('#test').val()` - the *value* of the textarea is not part of the HTML/DOM so will never be returned with `.html()` (whether you need/want it to or not, that's not how it works)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Is there any way to get an output like that < textarea >Mango< / textarea >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<textarea>` can contain innerHTML, which is displayed when there's no value:

```js
$("#test textarea").append("<strong>Inner</strong> html");
console.log($("textarea").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

though it's mostly ignored (as shown above) and lost when user enters a value.

So we can take advantage of that by *setting* the HTML to the value just before reading the HTML and it should work.   Here's a snippet that loops through all text areas as sets their HTML to the value:

```js
// empty on load
console.log($("#test").html())

$("button").click(() => {
    $("textarea").html(function() { return $(this).val(); });
    
    // output the outer #test div's innerHTML 
    // includes both textareas and their newly set HTML
    console.log($("#test").html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<button>click me</button>
```